# Flutter: How to reset TabController index upon bottom navigation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have a Flutter app with a Cupertino bottom navigation bar. The first page has tabbed views [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foBCz.png).

**What I'm trying to achieve**
Upon navigating away from that first page (or when tapping on any of the bottom navigation items/icons), I want the index of the tab controller on that first page to reset to 0 so that when I return to that first page, I see the initial tab by default (i.e. the car tab). The current default behaviour is that it will display whichever tab I left the page on.

How do I achieve the above? I've pasted in sample code below to somewhat replicate my scenario. I created the _resetTabIndex function that calls tabController.previousIndex and then tried to call that function whenever user navigates away from the page, but I couldn't get that to work. Thanks in advance for any help with this!

(NOTE: I have to stick with Cupertino bottom navigation because of other requirements in the real app)

***main.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'page1.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(TabBarDemo());
}

class TabBarDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

enum TabItem { page1, page2 }

class TabItemData {
  const TabItemData({@required this.title, @required this.icon});

  final String title;
  final IconData icon;

  static const Map<TabItem, TabItemData> allTabs = {
    TabItem.page1: TabItemData(title: 'Page 1', icon: Icons.shopping_cart_outlined),
    TabItem.page2: TabItemData(title: 'Page 2', icon: Icons.person_outline_rounded),
  };
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  TabItem _currentTab = TabItem.page1;

  Map<TabItem, WidgetBuilder> get widgetBuilders {
    return {
      TabItem.page1: (_) => Page1(),
      TabItem.page2: (_) => Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Center(child: Text('Page 2')),
          ),
          body: Center(child: Text('Page 2'))),
    };
  }

  void _resetTabIndex(TabItem tabItem) {
    setState(() => _currentTab = tabItem); // Ignore this. Set up for a behaviour in the complete app.

    // How can I amend this function to trigger the resetTabIndex method in page1.dart (which one alternative I thought might work)?

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoHomeScaffold(
      currentTab: _currentTab,
      onSelectTab: _resetTabIndex,
      widgetBuilders: widgetBuilders,
    );
  }
}

class CupertinoHomeScaffold extends StatelessWidget {
  CupertinoHomeScaffold({
    Key key,
    @required this.currentTab,
    @required this.onSelectTab,
    @required this.widgetBuilders,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final TabItem currentTab;
  final ValueChanged<TabItem> onSelectTab;
  final Map<TabItem, WidgetBuilder> widgetBuilders;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CupertinoTabScaffold(
      tabBar: CupertinoTabBar(
        items: [
          _buildItem(TabItem.page1),
          _buildItem(TabItem.page2),
        ],
        onTap: (index) => onSelectTab(TabItem.values[index]),
      ),
      tabBuilder: (context, index) {
        final item = TabItem.values[index];
        return CupertinoTabView(
          builder: (context) => widgetBuilders[item](context),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  BottomNavigationBarItem _buildItem(TabItem tabItem) {
    final itemData = TabItemData.allTabs[tabItem];
    final color = currentTab == tabItem ? Colors.indigo : Colors.grey;
    return BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(itemData.icon, color: color),
      title: Text(
        itemData.title,
        style: TextStyle(color: color),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

***page1.dart***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  TabController _tabController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: 2);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _tabController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  resetTabIndex() {
    setState(() {
      _tabController.previousIndex;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        bottom: TabBar(
          controller: _tabController,
          tabs: [
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_car)),
            Tab(icon: Icon(Icons.directions_bike)),
          ],
        ),
        title: Center(child: Text('Page 1')),
      ),
      body: TabBarView(
        controller: _tabController,
        children: [
          Icon(Icons.directions_car),
          Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When navigating away from that first page do this
`_tabController.animateTo(0,duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),curve:Curves.easeIn);`

Comment: thanks for the response. I'm new to Flutter so not sure where I would place this code? If I for example add it to the `resetTabIndex` function in `page1.dart`, how does the bottom nav, which is in `main.dart`, trigger that function?

Comment: @Camron you can add this where you are navigating from one page to the other. i think that is your _resetTabIndex function, so inside that will do